# (ILOG) IBM ODM 8.5 How to improve Rule Execution Server Performance?

Tags: websphere, rule-engine

I'm working on a big rule engine project. After deployment of rules and xom rule execution server doesn't respond or its response time gets longer and sometimes it freezes.

I set heap sizes on WebSphere server like this:  **-XX:MaxPermSize:1024m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m**

Is there any other way to configure it to perform better? Because sometimes I have to restart the related computer to work it safely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Rete execution mode? 99% of the time you will use Sequential, or maybe Fastpath depending on a number of factors. Very, very few people need Rete unless your are using forward rule chaining for example.

Unfortunately, by default, when you add rule tasks to rule flows in Rule Designer, it sets the execution mode to Rete.

So to check which execution mode you need to use, see [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.designer.run/optimizing_topics/tpc_opt_choose_execmode_criteria.html) for a checklist to go through within your decision service.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the BPM DeveloperWorks article [Improve performance for IBM Operational Decision Manager, Part 1: Reduce rule execution time](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1503_siddiqui1/1503_siddiqui1.html) for recommendations on ODM performance improvement, and also 
[Improve performance of rule execution and Rule Execution Server (RES) for ODM and JRules](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/173827/improve-performance-of-rule-execution-and-rule-exe.html)

Also, the default execution mode starting from ODM 8.7 is FastPath, which should provide the best performance for most use cases. You can set the default execution mode in Rule Designer, by clicking Window > Preferences > Rule Designer > Ruleflow.

Answer (score 0):

In my current project, I used both RetePlus and Sequential algorithms. Here are my impressions:

1. `RetePlus` = great for Decision Tables only, once it optimizes the critical path to evaluation of rules.
2. `Sequential` = great for simple calculation and atomic rules (Action Rules).

You can combine both approaches in a single orchestration. I did it in our project with a **nanosecond** performance, believe me.

Overall, it all depends on you business module and orchestration characteristics. Maybe you should review and improve your rules (are you accessing external entities or repositories within your business rules - it slows down your throughput).

RAM memory is important also, but is not enough. Improve the quality of your business rules, specially in your verbalizations. Maybe they are too complex or making too much computation several times.

Hope this helps.